# block a specific date in datapicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datapicker on my site where I have Monday and Tuesday blocked.
How can I block a very specific date eg 05/06/2013

The code I have now is as follows

```
noMondaysandtuesdays: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
return [(day == 0 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5|| day == 6)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtmsX/32/)
you can simply put desired dates which have to be blocked in `unavailableDates`array

```
 var unavailableDates = ["6-6-2013"];
    
    function unavailable(date) 
    {
      var dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" +  date.getFullYear();
        var day = date.getDay();
      if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0 && day != 1 && day != 2) 
      {
        return [true,"",""];
      } 
      else
      {
        return [false,"",""];
      }
    }
    $(function()
      {  $('#date').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });}
```

Hope this helps.